# Alexa Custom Skill AboutIntent not getting triggered under testing

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to debug an intent that is not getting trigguered during my skill development in developer.amazon.com online development platform (Alexa developer console.)

I have developed a skill based on an audio player template.  The issue I am having is the 'AboutIntent' is not getting triggered/executed after testing some sample uttererances.  The 'Evaluate Model' shows my utterance for instance 'Parrot Heads ask about Trop Rockit Radio'  apears to be a unique and clearly shows it is triggering in the Evaluate model under the build tab.   After build model is fully successful I went to the code tab and selected 'deploy' and then went to the 'test' tab and executed the  utterane 'parrot heads ask about trop rockit radio'.  Alexa seems to not know about this utterance and says a number of responses unreated such as 'Hmm, I don;t know that' etc.

The 'PlayStreamIntent'  and its sample utterance model works great.  The invocation name 'trop rockit raido'  does work.  But only the 'AbuoutIntent'  does not work under the Alexa test.  Again, I've done a model build, deploy and tested.   I've tried dozens of sample utterances that seem to properly trigger the 'AboutIntent' in the Evaluate Model tool, but does not get recognized in the Alexa test.

Here is the AboutIntent function:

```
const AboutIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AboutIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Trop Rockit Radio is a streaming radio service featuring tropical rock independent musicians with original music.  Are
you a parrot head?  Visit us at Rockit Broadcasting dot com and click on Trop Rockit Radio to learn more about us!   To continue listening say:
 resume, or say: stop to stop listening.';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};
```

In the Intent Editor,  I have the intent name as 'AboutIntent' and stripped the sample utterances down to just one "Parrot Heads ask about".  I had many other sample utterances, but stripped the problem to just one for debug/development.

The invocation name is "trop rockit radio" and does get invoked properly under test.  Also the other inent "PlayStreamIntent" with my 20+ sample utterances are working correctly.

What am I doing wrong?  Solutions? Suggestions?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure you made the skill kit changes in the right locale language and also testing in the same locale language?

Answer (score 1):

Once your playback starts, you can not handle custom intents. You can handle only player specific intents - check here https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html